# Using HTML Entities in a Zend Form Select

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, html-entities

I am populating a Select form element, and if I try to use HTML Entities in the value, it get's converted, rather than displaying the special character.

This code:

```
$form->field_name->addMultiOption('value', '&nbsp;&bull; label');
```

Renders:

```
<option value="one">&amp;nbsp;&amp;bull; label</option>
```

But I want it to be:

```
<option value="one">&nbsp;&bull; label</option>
```

How do I use HTML entities here?

---

**Hint?**

I dug in the code and found that it's using the `escape()` function from the Zend View Abstract on the label *AND* the value.  Maybe someone knows how to override/overload this function for a specific form element?  I don't want to override that behavior by default.

Function from the `Zend_View_Helper_FormSelect` class

```
protected function _build($value, $label, $selected, $disable)
{
    if (is_bool($disable)) {
        $disable = array();
    }

    $opt = '<option'
         . ' value="' . $this->view->escape($value) . '"'
         . ' label="' . $this->view->escape($label) . '"';

    // selected?
    if (in_array((string) $value, $selected)) {
        $opt .= ' selected="selected"';
    }

    // disabled?
    if (in_array($value, $disable)) {
        $opt .= ' disabled="disabled"';
    }

    $opt .= '>' . $this->view->escape($label) . "</option>";

    return $opt;
}
```

This is the function from the `Zend_View_Abstract` class:

```
private $_escape = 'htmlspecialchars';

/* SNIP */

public function escape($var)
{
    if (in_array($this->_escape, array('htmlspecialchars', 'htmlentities'))) {
        return call_user_func($this->_escape, $var, ENT_COMPAT, $this->_encoding);
    }

    return call_user_func($this->_escape, $var);
}
```

Comment: What do you want your expected output to be?

Comment: @Anthony - I've updated the question to address what my desired output is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out this isn't as complicated as I was making it.

I changed this:

```
$form->field_name->addMultiOption('value', '&nbsp;&bull; label');
```

To this:

```
$form->field_name->addMultiOption('value',
    html_entity_decode('&nbsp;&bull;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . ' label');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to switch off/clear Zend filters for specific fields when you populate them.

```
$form->getElement('yourElementName')->clearFilters();
// pupulate the element
```

When you clear the Zend filters, you can apply your own, prior populating.

Comment: I tried that just now but it didn't work.  I'm fairly certain that `clearFilters()` and filters in general only are applied to the values, not the labels.